# Vector of repeated index values

Tags: r

I have a vector of the following form:-

```
a <- c(4, 6, 3, 6, 1)
```

What I want is to make a vector such that it has the index of the vector `a` the number of times the value of that index in vector `a`.

Like the first index has value `4`, so there should be `4` ones, followed by `6` twos, followed by `3` threes, and so on.

Then resulting vector should be of the following form:-

```
b <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rep` as :

```
a <- c(4, 6, 3, 6, 1)
rep(seq_along(a), a)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sequence`

```
cumsum(sequence(a) == 1)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5
```

---

Or using `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(a) %>% 
     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
     uncount(a)
```